# Stuck two days on this NoReverseMatch thing

Tags: django, model-view-controller

Coded in Pycharm
Django version 3.2.6

- Project hw_v2
- app

  - aftersales
  - ...
- Templates

Project URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(('index.urls', 'index'), namespace='index')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('mkt/', include(('marketing.urls', 'marketing'), namespace='mkt')),
    path('com/', include(('commercial.urls', 'comercial'), namespace='com')),
    path('aft/', include(('aftersales.urls', 'aft'), namespace='aft')),
    path('gen/', include(('general.urls', 'general'), namespace='gen')),
    path('user/',include(('user.urls','user'),namespace='user')),
    path('bootstrapTable/',include('bootstrapTable.urls')),]
```

App/aftersales URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.aft,name='afti'),
path('edit/<int:id>',views.aft_edit,name='aft_edit'),
path('view/<int:id>',views.aft_view,name='aft_view'),]
```

Error Page HTML:

```
<td>
    <a href="{% url 'aft:aft_view' id=itm.id %}" class="lni lni-magnifier"></a>
    <a href="#" class="lni lni-close"></a>
    <a href="{% url 'aft:aft_edit' id=itm.id %}" class="fadeIn animated bx bx-edit-alt"></a>
</td>
```

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /aft/view/1
    Reverse for 'aft' not found. 'aft' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/aft/view/1
    Django Version: 3.2.6
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for 'aft' not found. 'aft' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
    Exception Location: D:\0 PROJECTS\14 django_website_ali\hw_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    Python Executable:  D:\0 PROJECTS\14 django_website_ali\hw_v2\venv\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.9.2
    Python Path:    [WindowsPath('D:/0 PROJECTS/14 django_website_ali/hw_v2'),
'D:\\0 PROJECTS\\14 django_website_ali\\hw_v2\\app',
 'D:\\0 PROJECTS\\14 django_website_ali\\hw_v2',
 'D:\\0 PROJECTS\\14 django_website_ali\\hw_v2',
 'D:\\0 PROJECTS\\14 django_website_ali\\hw_v2\\app',
 'D:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2020.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib',
 'D:\\Program Files\\Python39',
 'D:\\0 PROJECTS\\14 django_website_ali\\hw_v2\\venv',
 'D:\\0 PROJECTS\\14 django_website_ali\\hw_v2\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'D:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2020.1\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Fri, 20 Aug 2021 09:01:56 +0800
```

app/aftersales/views:

```
def aft_edit(request, id):
    item = FFREntry.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        print(item)
        return render(request, 'aft_edit.html', locals())
    elif request.method == "POST":
        keys = ['engineer', 'date', 'complaint', 'client', 'e_code', 'inv_type', 'inv_model', 'sn', 'region', 'state',
                'f_type', 'f_type_d', 'solution', 'is_warr', 'compl', 'remark', 'img', 'video'
                ]
        for key in keys:
            if request.POST.get(key):
                dict={key:request.POST.get(key)}
                FFREntry.objects.filter(id=id).update(**dict)
                FFREntry.save

        return redirect('aft_view',id=id)


def aft_view(request, id):
    item = FFREntry.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'aft_view.html', locals())
```

I've been stuck here for two days.
The error came out of nowhere.
One sec ago, it was all ok. Then, the error jumped out.
I am not a programmer. Coding is just a hobby. I have no one I can consult with.
So please please please, save me.

***LATEST UPDATES***

The project is working now. It is totally creepy and strange. Below is what I did:

1. In #app/aftersales/url.py

```
    path('', views.aft,name='aft'),
    path('aft/edit/<int:id>',views.aft_edit,name='aft_edit'),
    path('view/<int:id>',views.aft_view,name='aft_view'),
]
```

I added 'aft/' in the second path(). Totally out of desperation.
obviously, it's wrong. And error popped.

2. I deleted the 'aft/'.
   **Then everything goes back to normal.**

I have no idea what happened.
Thanks to everyone who gave me advice! Deeply!

Comment: Is "App/aftersales URL" a typo?

Comment: 'aftersales.apps.AftersalesConfig', is how it registrered in settings.py.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `aft:`?

Comment: No, tried and failed.

Comment: Can you also share the result of `python manage.py show_urls | grep aft`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `{% url 'aft' %}` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your views I can't be sure, but the issue is likely in your template due to the way arguments are being passed into your template tag.

```
<td>
    <a href="{% url 'aft:aft_view' itm.id %}" class="lni lni-magnifier"></a>
    <a href="#" class="lni lni-close"></a>
    <a href="{% url 'aft:aft_edit' itm.id %}" class="fadeIn animated bx bx-edit-alt"></a>
</td>
```

Remove the key / equals sign and simply pass the argument value. Assuming the context you're passing the template includes `itm` this should render the links correctly and the reverse match error will go away.

Before: `id=itm.id`

After: `itm.id`

Note that I tested this on one of my own templates by adding the arguments as key value pairs like in your example and got the same error.

Comment: Thank you. But this solution didn't work out. I posted the views.py.

Comment: This is what fixed it. When you made changes to urls.py it was then applied. Try putting it back the way it was in the template and it will break again.